# My TextField is not editable

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I know it is a very simple Question, but the TextField is not Editable.

I have three UIViews, in each UIView contains three TextFields. The TextFields in the 2nd and 3rd UIView are working perfectly. But in the TextFields in the 1st UIView are really weird.

Let the TextFields are First, Middle , Last Name . First TextField is working fine, Middle is working only sometimes (it means i need to touch several times) and at last, the Last Name TextField is COMPLETELY not working.

What could be the problem ?

**EDIT:**

```
_bgScrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
_bgScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
_bgScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

_bgScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO; 
[_bgScrollView addSubview:FirstView]; 
[_bgScrollView addSubview:SecondView];
[_bgScrollView addSubview:ThirdView]; 
[self layoutSubViews];
_bgScrollView is scrollView Object
```

Comment: try to put a blank textfield . if it is editable then there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: did you check on device...try removing them..and adding them again..

Comment: Tried that too, couldn't figure out what is the Exact problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you connected it with XIB and also delegate it ?Also have you implemented this function?

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [self isEditing];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have created an object and connected it in the xib and delegate too. Still it is not working . Looks Strange !!

Comment: How about the function? Have you implemented it? Also @Thiba may be correct. What is the structure of your view?

Comment: @Roy : you answer me with only 1 question. What is the structure of your view?

Comment: How about posting some basic code and whole structure in your question?

Comment: I guess there is no problem with the code because, when we connect the object in xib and delegate it, when the user select that TextField now, the keyboard layout will pop-up irrespective of the code. But i wll post some code where the three views are joined

Comment: _bgScrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    _bgScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _bgScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: _bgScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
        [_bgScrollView addSubview:FirstView];
        [_bgScrollView addSubview:SecondView];
        [_bgScrollView addSubview:ThirdView];
     [self layoutSubViews];

Comment: _bgScrollView is scrollView Object

Comment: can you show the scene shot. AS after having a look at your code,it seems that what the problem is with overlapping of your views. Also r u showing them all together?

Comment: I am sorry that, I am not supposed to post code/Screen shots as it is confidential.Three views can be viewed by scrolling. I am little confused because the First TextField in 1st UIView is working , where the Second TextField works only if i press twice or thrice and the Third TextField is not at all working. HELP ME !

Comment: why don't you use UITableview and use section instead of 3 views and scrollview??

Comment: I Guess there is no way for this rather than creating the project again OR using UITableVIew. i thought this problem can be resolved. Anyway thanks @ Sarah, i will start over again .

Comment: Thats fine Roy. Glad to help you. Also would like to tell you that even I had same issue where I had to use 3-4 views. And I took the image that looked like 4 view but was only one view and took a scrollview and on the same had taken the uitextfields and labels and implemented. Thought to share with you. hope that helps you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure no other view is sitting on top of the text field - sorry i did not know how to comment, so put it as an answer.

Comment: there's an add comment below every answer or a question. You can click on it to comment :) :)

Comment: Let me tell one more thing, i have three UIView, the TextFields in the other two UIView are working fine. But only in this FirstView , the TextField are working wierd

Comment: try putting [yourView bringSubviewtofront:yourTextField] and try!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have a transparent image view/button//or nay other thing above the text field in the nib...that might not let the text field get any touches..

If you have make it as an IBOutlet.. then call the

`[[self YourTextField] becomeFirstResponder]` in your `ViewDidLoad`

**If it works..then there is problem in your xib.**.the text field is not getting any touches.

Comment: See the Main Question, i have edited. If the View is transparent or whatever , the First and Middle TextField should not be editable right ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that  userInteractionEnabled=YES in textField

Comment: I am sure that i have kept it in the coding as well as in the xib settings. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to put the following in you ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //textField's Outlet should be declared in the (.h) file
    //and synthesized in the (.m) class
    //then add the code below.
    [self textField].enabled = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

or just edit the viewDidLoad that should already be there.

Then, later on, specify manually, with code, that editing should begin, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this by accidentally unchecking "User Interaction Enabled" on the entire view! I had meant to do that just on the header image. Well, I am just learning the thing...